# PostgreSQL: Can we use "varchar" instead of "nvarchar" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, varchar, nvarchar

Can we use `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` for same use in PostgreSQL?

Because I am unable to use `nvarchar` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: -1 Check [character set support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use varchar in postgresql. Please refer this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-character.html